# How to retrieve selected items from a list of items?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In my application, user is able to select few items and see the details of all.
I know that I can use the Criteria and using its Restrictions.disjunction(), I can define the 
"OR"; however, I need to retrieve the id of selected items from a list which makes it difficult to create the query using criteria.

```
Criteria cre = session.createCriteria(Category.class,"category");
cre.add(Restrictions.disjunction()) //?????
for(int i=0;i<selection.size();i++){
   cre.add(Restrictions.eq("category.items",selection.get(i)); 
}
....


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
public List<CategoryItem> getItems() {
    return this.items;
}
```

Another method is to send separate queries which I reckon thats an inefficient approach.

Comment: `from Category c join c.items i where i.id in :yourList` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ean mentioned just use the following:

```
from Category c join c.items i where i.id in :yourList
```